# How to get the seconds since epoch from the time + date output of gmtime()?

Tags: python, datetime, time

How do you do reverse `gmtime()`, where you put the time + date and get the number of seconds?

I have strings like `'Jul 9, 2009 @ 20:02:58 UTC'`, and I want to get back the number of seconds between the epoch and July 9, 2009.

I have tried `time.strftime` but I don't know how to use it properly, or if it is the correct command to use.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you got here because a search engine told you this is how to get the Unix timestamp, stop reading this answer. Scroll up one.

If you want to reverse `time.gmtime()`, you want `calendar.timegm()`.

```
>>> calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
1293581619.0
```

You can turn your string into a time tuple with `time.strptime()`, which returns a time tuple that you can pass to `calendar.timegm()`:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> import time
>>> calendar.timegm(time.strptime('Jul 9, 2009 @ 20:02:58 UTC', '%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S UTC'))
1247169778
```

More information about calendar module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html)

Comment: If you are looking for the current unix epoch time please refer to @DanJ's comment or naren's answer, this answer  is incorrect!

Comment: Answers like this make me laugh.  I'm not exactly sure why.  I feel like a basketball.

Comment: @NathanChappell Search engine optimization is weird, and "how to get seconds since epoch" is the only part of the question many people read. See the comment above suggesting that this answer is incorrect, since it answers the question that was actually asked.

Comment: If you came here simple looking for how to get epoch time in python, answer is -> `time.time()`

Answer (score 861):

Use the [time](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html) module:

```py
import time    
epoch_time = int(time.time())
```

Comment: @DanJ: it is number of elapsed seconds since Epoch (a fixed moment in time) and it is the same in any timezone. Though if we ignore time instances around leap seconds; it is easy to convert it to UTC if `time` uses Unix epoch (1970).

Comment: Note this isn't what the OP was asking for, but it's what *I* wanted.  So +1.

Comment: it is the answer to what is asked in the title: "getting the time since the epoch". +1

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian this gives epoch to seconds. How can I get the resolution upto miliseconds using the same above answer?

Comment: ok I found out int(round(time.time() * 1000)) will give it in milliseconds.

Comment: to extend [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548684/how-to-get-the-seconds-since-epoch-from-the-time-date-output-of-gmtime-in-py#comment29834679_13342744): `time.time()` value does NOT depend on the local timezone (if we exclude "right" timezones and the like) e.g., if it returns POSIX time (as it does on most systems) then it is the number of SI seconds since the Epoch (1970-01-01UTC) not counting leap seconds. This value *can* be converted to UTC (excluding leap seconds) but *it is not UTC*. @MarlonAbeykoon: I like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21858377/4279)

Answer (score 10):

Note that `time.gmtime` maps timestamp `0` to `1970-1-1 00:00:00`.

```
In [61]: import time       
In [63]: time.gmtime(0)
Out[63]: time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)
```

`time.mktime(time.gmtime(0))` gives you a timestamp shifted by an amount that depends on your locale, which in general may not be 0.

```
In [64]: time.mktime(time.gmtime(0))
Out[64]: 18000.0
```

The inverse of `time.gmtime` is `calendar.timegm`:

```
In [62]: import calendar    
In [65]: calendar.timegm(time.gmtime(0))
Out[65]: 0
```

Comment: This gives better explanation and example to time.mktime (which take current  timezone into account), thanks

Comment: @Jkm: do NOT use `mktime()` with `gmtime()`. `mktime()` accepts your *local time* but `gmtime()` returns *UTC time* -- your local timezone may and is likely to be different. "timestamp relative to your locale" is non-sense: POSIX timestamp does not depend on your locale (local timezone) -- it is the same value around the world. "seconds since epoch" is POSIX timestamp in most cases (even on Windows) -- things like "right" timezones that use TAI time scale are not common. See [Does Python's time.time() return the local or UTC timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035913/4279)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian You are right. Actually I got a few issue about `mktime()` recently. For some python web server (Tornado for example), since the process keep running, even if I change the system locale, the `mktime()` called by the web server API still use the **old timezone** to generate the time object. I have to switch to `gmtime()` and manually apply the gmt offset.

Answer (score 9):

```
ep = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)
x = (datetime.datetime.utcnow()- ep).total_seconds()
```

This should be different from `int(time.time())`, but it is safe to use something like `x % (60*60*24)`

[datetime — Basic date and time types:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

> Unlike the time module, the datetime module does not support leap seconds.

Answer (score 5):

```
t = datetime.strptime('Jul 9, 2009 @ 20:02:58 UTC',"%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Comment: I cant access strptime for some reason. I have imported datetime

Comment: @calccrypto you have to either `from datetime import datetime` or do `datetime.datetime.strptime`

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways, depending on your original timestamp:

`mktime()` and `timegm()`

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html