# How do I reference the epoch number within a Keras generator?

Tags: python, generator, keras

I'm building a Python generator to be consumed by the Keras fit_generator function. I want to use the current epoch count in my generator to adjust a value. Is there any way to reference this number?

```
def generate_arrays_from_file(path):
    while 1:
    f = open(path)
    for line in f:
        x, y = process_line(line)
        epoch_number = ?
        x = x + epoch_number
        yield (x, y)
    f.close()

model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_file('/my_file.txt'),
        samples_per_epoch=10000, nb_epoch=10)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548684/how-to-get-the-seconds-since-epoch-from-the-time-date-output-of-gmtime-in-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def generate_arrays_from_file(path, samples_per_epoch):
    samples_produced_in_current_epoch = 0
    epoch_number = 1
    while 1:
    f = open(path)
    for line in f:
        x, y = process_line(line)
        x = x + epoch_number
        samples_produced += x.shape[0]
        if samples_produced_in_current_epoch > samples_per_epoch:
            epoch_number += 1
            samples_produced_in_current_epoch = 0      
        yield (x, y)

    f.close()
```

Comment: Yeah, that works! It would be nice if there was a way to reference it directly, but this will help me achieve what I'm going for. You could even make this a tad more concise with `epoch_number = samples_produced_in_current_epoch / samples_per_epoch + 1`

Comment: You could have problems with overflow if the number of epochs and samples are high