# Converting Pandas DatetimeIndex to a numeric format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

I want to convert the DatetimeIndex in my DataFrame to float format,which can be analysed in my model.Could someone tell me how to do it? Do I need to use  date2num()function?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Convert to `Timedelta` and extract the total seconds from `dt.total_seconds`:

```
df

        date
0 2013-01-01
1 2013-01-02
2 2013-01-03
3 2013-01-04
4 2013-01-05
5 2013-01-06
6 2013-01-07
7 2013-01-08
8 2013-01-09
9 2013-01-10

pd.to_timedelta(df.date).dt.total_seconds()

0    1.356998e+09
1    1.357085e+09
2    1.357171e+09
3    1.357258e+09
4    1.357344e+09
5    1.357430e+09
6    1.357517e+09
7    1.357603e+09
8    1.357690e+09
9    1.357776e+09
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Or, maybe, the data would be more useful presented as an `int` type:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.date).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)

0    1356998400
1    1357084800
2    1357171200
3    1357257600
4    1357344000
5    1357430400
6    1357516800
7    1357603200
8    1357689600
9    1357776000
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Try df.date.values.astype(float) once

Comment: @Bharathshetty `cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]`

Comment: I think you got a wrong solution try `pd.to_datetime(pd.to_timedelta(df.date).dt.total_seconds().values[0])` Its giving 1970 ...

Comment: @Bharathshetty that's just how the function works. it doesn't understand that the number is the epochs. The solution isn't wrong. You should understand that the epoch time of 1970 is 0, that's when the Unix OS was developed at bell labs - hence the name "Unix Timestamp".

Comment: I just thought op wanted the float representation of the datetime . I dont know what OP wants in reality. Lets see when he come back

Answer (score 11):

Use astype float i.e if you have a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1998-03-01 00:00:01', '2001-04-01 00:00:01','1998-06-01 00:00:01','2001-08-01 00:00:01','2001-05-03 00:00:01','1994-03-01 00:00:01'] })
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['x'] = list('abcdef')
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Then

```
df.index.values.astype(float)

array([  8.88710401e+17,   9.86083201e+17,   8.96659201e+17,
     9.96624001e+17,   9.88848001e+17,   7.62480001e+17])

pd.to_datetime(df.index.values.astype(float))

DatetimeIndex(['1998-03-01 00:00:01', '2001-04-01 00:00:01',
           '1998-06-01 00:00:01', '2001-08-01 00:00:01',
           '2001-05-03 00:00:01', '1994-03-01 00:00:01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Note that seconds since the epoch as of 2017 are of the order 10e9, so 10e17 is incorrect. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46502880/4909087 and run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548684/how-to-get-the-seconds-since-epoch-from-the-time-date-output-of-gmtime-in-py

Comment: But when you convert it back to pd.to_datetime original date is returned na

Comment: Yes, but I presume OP wants to work with the epoch time. I don't know what astype gives, but it seems like a bug? It's definitely not the epoch time.

Comment: I get AttributeError  when I use timedelta

Comment: Oh, sorry. I started off with a datetime column.  Let me modify.

Comment: `df['date'].values.astype(float)` will give the same answer you got but in powers of 18

Comment: That is working as expected @Bharath, but I wonder if there is a solution to only keep the date part when using `values.astype(int)`? Currently I receive `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.date'`

Comment: @gies0r convert the datetime.date to pandas datetime dtype and then cast to int i.e `pd.to_datetime(df.index.date).astype(int)`

Answer (score 8):

I found another solution:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64').astype(int).astype(float)
```

Comment: I've checked it and it works for me. Can u say more about your problem?
For me df['date'] has dtype: object, because I read it from csv. Maybe this is the difference.
U can try this:
`df['date'].astype(int).astype(float)`

Comment: If you are storing `datetime.date` objects in your column, conversion directly to float will fail. Date objects may be converted to `datetime64` in order to get the resolution required for a numeric representation, but these may not be converted to floating-point values, so the intermediate step of converting to int is necessary.

Comment: Using `astype(int)` raises warning, it suggests to use `.view(int)`: `flatten_df['first_year_date'].astype('datetime64').view(int).astype(float)`

Answer (score 6):

I believe this offers another solution, here assuming a dataframe with a DatetimeIndex.

```
pd.to_numeric(df.index, downcast='float')
# although normally I would prefer an integer, and to coerce errors to NaN
pd.to_numeric(df.index, errors = 'coerce',downcast='integer')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want specific parts of your `DateTimeIndex`, try this:

```
ADDITIONAL = 1
ddf_c['ts_part_numeric'] = ((ddf_c.index.dt.year * (10000 * ADDITIONAL)) + (ddf_c.index.dt.month * (100 * ADDITIONAL)) + ((ddf_c.index.dt.day) * ADDITIONAL))
```

Output is

```
20190523
20190524
```

Could adjust it to your time resolution needed.