# Need to read excel dates as decimals without automatically converting to date time

Tags: excel, pandas

I am reading in an excel sheet that has column `'Time (hr)'` times in hours, minutes, seconds formatted like this : 64:45:00
I need to convert this to 64.75 hours 
When I read this in with read_excel it automatically converts it to **1900-01-02 16:45**

I have tried using dtype, converters, date_parse options in the read_excel function but always get an error

```
data = xl.parse(header = [0], dtype = {'Time (hr)': np.float64})

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

EDIT:
I found out that some of the values in the Time (hr) column are less than 24 hours therefore are read in as time only.  For example 10:45:00 is just read in as a time so when I tried the solution I got this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'

Answer (score 0):

You can try **creating a dataframe** first from the excel file using the following code `test_df = xl.parse(name)`

and then **convert the date** column to a int type like `test_df['Time (hr)'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").astype(int)`

Comment: When I do that I get this error:
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: You can probably check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46502880/6908282

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my test file `dates.xlsx` looks like:

[image: example data for testing]

Read it in and parse the dates as usual:

```
df = pd.read_excel('dates.xlsx', parse_dates=['Time (hr)'])

            Time (hr)
0 1900-01-02 16:45:00
1 1900-01-02 07:10:00
2 1900-01-05 15:59:01
```

Excel's day one is 1-Jan-1900, so zero is:

```
epoch = dt.datetime(1899, 12, 31)
```

Subtract the epoch to get a `timedelta` and then convert to total seconds:

```
df['seconds'] = (df['Time (hr)'] - epoch).dt.total_seconds()

            Time (hr)   seconds
0 1900-01-02 16:45:00  233100.0
1 1900-01-02 07:10:00  198600.0
2 1900-01-05 15:59:01  489541.0
```

Make column for total hours:

```
df['hours'] = df.seconds / 3600

            Time (hr)   seconds       hours
0 1900-01-02 16:45:00  233100.0   64.750000
1 1900-01-02 07:10:00  198600.0   55.166667
2 1900-01-05 15:59:01  489541.0  135.983611
```